# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android

I tried this code (seen below) and it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'customHandler'", I am a beginner so I don't know yet how to fix this problem.
It would be awesome, if you could explain me how to fix it.

I am thankfull for every help :D

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //------------------
    //------------------
    android.os.Handler customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //write here whatever you want to repeat
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

I am trying to make a method run from the begining once every minute.

Comment: have you googled the error message?

Comment: The problem is that customHandler is not visible in the run() scope.

Comment: working yet? Have you reviewed the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customHandler is a **local variable** in your method `onCreate`, so method `run()` cannot see it.

Make customHandler a **member variable** of your class to fix.

```
//Member variable
android.os.Handler customHandler;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //Assign value
      customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
      customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}


    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
          public void run()
          {
            //USE the value
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
          }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `customHandler` object is not visible from your `updateTimerThread`.

Try to change the visibility of this variable by moving it outside of your method.

Here is an exemple:

```
android.os.Handler customHandler; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //------------------
    //------------------
    customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //write here whatever you want to repeat
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

But using a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and a [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) may be a better solution than recursively calling postDelay on your handler.

It's makes cleaner code and it assure you that it will be runned at a specific frequency (for example every minutes) whereas your solution only allows to fix the delay between the end of a run and the beginning of the next one (if it take 30s to run and delay is 1 minute, it will run every 1.5mn)

```
// declare your timer
Timer basicTimer; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //------------------
    //------------------
    // create a Timer
    basicTimer = new Timer();
    // create the periodic task, here it's an anonymous class
    TimerTask updateTimerThread = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //write here whatever you want to repeat
            // no need to call postDelayed
        }
    };
    // schedule the task to run every minutes
    basicTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateTimerThread, 0, 60*1000); // 1minutes = 60000 ms
}
```